# How to change shiny widget colour

Tags: css, r, shiny

Using the [shiny widget gallery](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/widget-gallery.html) as reference, I was wondering whether it's possible to change the colour scheme of widgets? Specifically, while some seem to inherit css theme elements, some - such as the sliderInput widget - retain the default blue.

As a related aside, highlighting text within shiny apps also adopts a blue highlight colour. I'm sure there is a straightforward way to change this along the same lines?

Comment: It seems that the slider input widgets that you mention specifically are styled with a different stylesheet: most default shiny widgets seem to get their theme from `bootstrap.min.css`, but not the sliders. If you want to change them, their css classes are `.irs-bar` and `.irs-bar-edge` (assuming you know how to manipulate css properties)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with manipulating CSS classes, would you mind expanding?

Comment: A good place to start would be [this Shiny article](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) explaining how to include CSS styling in your Shiny app. For basic CSS syntax, I found [this tutorial at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) quite helpful when starting off. If you familiarize yourself a bit with these sources, my comment and the answer below should make a bit more sense.

Comment: Mikko, sorry for the delayed response, but having had a play with this (+ getting my head around CSS) I can't actually seem to find the `.iris-bar` property that I'm looking for. I've tried color, background-color, border-bottom-color, none of which seem to work. Could you advise?

Comment: Strange, as far as I can tell, `background-color` should have done the trick. I posted a short working example for the slider as an answer, see if that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a minimal example for the specific case of modifying the colour of a Shiny slider bar:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # CSS styles
  tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar {background: yellow}")),
  tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar {border-top: 1px solid green}")),
  tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar-edge {background: red}")),
  tags$style(HTML(".irs-bar-edge {border: 1px solid red}")),

  # Slider
  sliderInput("slider", "Pick a value:", value = 4, min = 1, max = 10)

)

server <- function(input, output) {}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

If you're using a browser that supports it (for example Chrome or Firefox), you can right click on a web page and select "Inspect Element". This will open a viewer that shows you the HTML source code and the attached styles etc. It's really handy for understanding the structure of HTML elements.

---

Following the other answer, you could also add this line to your `ui` tags in order to change the selection highlight colour:

```
tags$style(HTML("::selection {background: tomato}")),
```

If you find yourself in a situation where you're modifying lots of different CSS styles and cluttering your `ui.R` with `style` tags, you can also write your CSS in a separate `.css` file and include it in your Shiny app by using the `includeCSS` function - this will make your code a lot cleaner, and you gain the added benefit of being able to get CSS syntax highlighting from a text editor.

Here's an example of using an external CSS file to create a "tomato theme", essentially changing the slider and selection theme colour to `tomato`:

**1.** Create a file called `tomatoTheme.css` in your app folder:

```css
::selection {
    background: tomato
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: tomato
}

.irs-single {background: tomato}

[class|="irs-bar"] {
    background: tomato;
    border: tomato
}
```

**2.** Include the CSS in your ui by using `includeCSS`:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # CSS styles
  includeCSS("tomatoTheme.css"),

  # Slider
  sliderInput("slider", "Pick a value:", value = 4, min = 1, max = 10)

)

server <- function(input, output) {}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: That worked exactly, thanks very much. All that I would change now is the background of the hovering number above the slider, which also assumes the `bootstrap.min.css` blue. I've had a scan through the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/) reference but can't see which property I should be changing?

Comment: I believe the hovering number element has the class `.irs-single`, so using `.irs-single {background: tomato}` should work.

Answer (score 3):

I've never worked with this, but it seems to be built off of Bootstrap so each item has the same elements.

`.well` is the gray background, it has a default background and border of `background-color: #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;`

`h3` is the headers on the page, 'Action Button`,`Single Checkbox', etc..

`.btn-default` is the basic button with these base styles `color: #333; background-color: #fff; border-color: #ccc;`

---

As far as changing a highlight selection:

```
::selection {
  background: red; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: red; /* Gecko Browsers */
}
```

You can also change the color of the text while highlighted using the `color` attribute.