# R Shiny - Display static text outside sidebar panel

Tags: r, shiny

I want to display static text outside of the sidebar panel in Shiny. I am able to display the text inside the sidebar panel. However, if I try to display text outside of the sidebar panel then I get this error: "Error in match.arg: 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector".

Below is an example code which displays the sentence "This is a static text" inside the sidebar panel. I want to display the text "just below" the sidebar panel but not inside the panel window.

The code below gives me this output:

[image: this output] but I want it to look like this:

[image: like this] How do I achieve this?

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30),
         h5("This is a static text")
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sidebarPanel` function will put everything inside a `form` with class `well`. One hacky solution (maybe there is a better one) is to create a custom function `siderbarPanel`function to put elements outside the `form`. Below is your code with the function `sidebarPanel2` that is just a customization of the original function to put element "just below". You can put anything, not just text.

```R
library(shiny)

sidebarPanel2 <- function (..., out = NULL, width = 4) 
{
  div(class = paste0("col-sm-", width), 
    tags$form(class = "well", ...),
    out
  )
}

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel2(fluid = FALSE,
      sliderInput("bins",
                 "Number of bins:",
                 min = 1,
                 max = 50,
                 value = 30),
      out = h5("This is a static text")
    ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you. That solves my problem. I am marking this as a correct answer until I find a better solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

One alternative: you could not use `sidebarLayout()` at all, and just define your own `shiny-input-container` styles (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31832831/1186342) for more examples adjusting slider component styles). Then you can make more complex arrangements of input widgets, text, and plots with `fluidRow()` and `column()` nesting ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25341329/1186342)).

```r
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  #CSS Styles
  tags$style(HTML(
    paste0(".shiny-input-container {background-color: #f5f5f5; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;",
           "padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; border-radius: 3px;}")
           )),

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  #use column to mimic sidebarPanel
  column(
    width = 4,
    sliderInput("bins",
                "Number of bins:",
                min = 1,
                max = 50,
                value = 30),    
    hr(),
    h5("This is a static text")
  ),

  #use column to mimic main panel
  column(
    width = 8,
    plotOutput("distPlot")
  )

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>